# NULL node or space when using fgets and strtok and trying to print nodes created

Tags: c, linked-list, fgets, strtok

Having an issue with getting a space or NULL node, when it tries to print the sentence out.

Input file is txt file with content "this is our time to shine" without the quotes

Two empty output files are also present for later output not pertaining to the current problem.

Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 200
typedef struct data{
    char *word;
    struct data *next;
}node;
node *head=NULL;
node *copy=NULL;
node *prev=NULL;
int _log=-1;
void read_content(char *filename);//prototype
node* create_word(char *string);//prototype
void add_word(node *word);//prototype
void delete_word(char *string);//prototype
void print_words();//prototype
void log_it(node *curr, node *next, int op);//prototype
void undo();//prototype


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc!=4){
        printf("\nInvalid parameters");
        return 0;
    }//end if
    head=malloc(sizeof(node));
    copy=malloc(sizeof(node));
    prev=malloc(sizeof(node));
    read_content(argv[1]);
    int option=4;
    int stringLength;
    char *del_word=malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    char *word=malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    node *addit;
    while(option!=0){
        printf("\nSentence: ");
        print_words();
        printf("\nMenu: \n(1) Add new word\n(2) Delete word\n(3) Undo last action\n(0) Exit\nOption: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        if(option==1){//add new word
            printf("\nPlease enter new word: ");
            scanf("%s", word);
            addit=create_word(word);
            printf("\n%s", word);
            add_word(addit);
        }//end if
        else if(option==2){//delete option
            printf("\nPlease enter word to delete: ");
            scanf("%s", del_word);
            delete_word(del_word);
        }//end if
        else if(option==3){
            undo();
        }//end if
        else if(option==0){
            printf("\nTerminating program");
            return 0;
        }//end if
        else{
            printf("\nUnrecognized option");
        }//end else
    }//end while
    return 0;
}//end main

//this is course cs2050
void read_content(char *filename){
    FILE *input=fopen(filename, "r");
    if(input==NULL){
        head=NULL;
        printf("\nEmpty list started");
    }
    char s[MAX];
    char* token;
    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), input) != NULL)
    {
      int length = strlen(s)-1;
      if(s[length] == '\n') 
         s[length] = '\0';
    }//end while

    token = strtok(s, " ");
    //head = NULL;
    node *newnode;
    while (token)
    {
            char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token));
            strcpy(s, token);
            newnode=create_word(s);//create new node 
            printf("\n%s", newnode->word);//error checking
            add_word(newnode);//add to linked list 
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }//end while

    fclose(input);
}//end read content

//creates node from char string
node* create_word(char *string){
    node *newNode=malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->word=string;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    return newNode;
}//end create word

//adds node to link list
void add_word(node *word){
    node *current=head;
    if(current==NULL){
        current=word;
    }//end if
    else{
        while(current->next!=NULL){
            current=current->next;

        }//end while;

        current->next=word;
    }//end else
    //printf("\n%s", current->next->word);
    _log=1;
}//end add word


void delete_word(char *string){
    node *current=head;
    node *previous=NULL;
    while(string!=current->word){
        previous=current;
        current=current->next;
    }//end while
    if(string==current->word){
        previous->next=current->next;
        copy->word=current->word;
        copy->next=current->next;
        prev=current;
    }//end while
    _log=-1;
}//end delete word

//function to print linked list as sentence
void print_words(){
    node *printhead=head;
    //printf("\n");
    //printhead=printhead->next;
    while(printhead!=NULL){
        printf("%s ", printhead->word);
        printhead=printhead->next;  
    }//end while
}//end print words


void log_it(node *curr, node *next, int op){

}//end log it


void undo(){
    node *current=head;
    node *prev=malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(_log==-1)//last action was delete word
    {

    }//end if
    else if(_log==1)//last action was insert word
    {

    }//end else if
    else{

    }//end else
}//end undo
```

Output below:

print_words() prints this:
(null) this is our time to shine

Seems that there is a null node coming into play at the beginning but can't seem to find the reason why.

Comment: `}//end if` - just ***no please.***

Comment: Also, `char *del_word=malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);` should be `char del_word[MAX];` instead, or at least don't forget to `free()` it before exiting if you still insist on local-scope dynamic mallocation for some non-obvious reason.

Comment: Why not `int _log = -1; // set to -1`?

Comment: Note that this: `void print_words();//prototype` is not what it says. In C, that is a function declaration, but it is ***not*** a prototype. It says that the function `print_words()` exists and returns no value, but it says nothing at all about the argument list except that it is not a 'varargs' argument list. To make it into a prototype, you have to write: `void print_words(void);//prototype`. Also, for a question posted to Stack Overflow, it is best to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)); avoid empty, incomplete functions like `undo()` or `log_it()`.

Comment: Also, it is best to end messages with a newline (so that they appear in a timely manner in the output), rather than starting messages with a newline.

Comment: You say that the data file contains `this is our time to shine`; you also say that the output is `(null) this is course cs2050`.  Is this a grotesque mismatch between what is in the input and the output, or a 'typo' in the question?  You have a buffer overflow at: `char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(token)); strcpy(s, token);` — you need to allocate `strlen(token)+1` characters.

Comment: to the first reply about the print_words prototype, YES it actually is a prototype as it does specify that it doesn't return anything by having the "void" in the front of it, any function that doesn't take an input requires nothing within the () so "void print_words();//prototype" functions fine as a prototype. As I said before it's not a problem with the print function.  Its a problem getting a NULL node at the beginning.  As for the allocating I'll take a look at that one, although it seems like this would not cause the issue I'm having considering.  Regardless thanks for the help.

Comment: No.  Actually, `void print_words();` is not a prototype in C.  If you are thinking of C++ (a very different language from C), then it is a prototype.  In C, `void print_words();` is not a prototype.  It is a function declaration; it is **not** (repeat ***not***) a prototype.

Comment: so you're saying that something such as void add_word(node *word);//prototype   is also not a prototype because it doesn't follow your not(repeat not) format

Comment: No; if you specify the argument list as in `void add_word(node *word);`, then you have a prototype.  If you don't specify the argument list, as in `void print_words();`, you have not got a prototype.  It is simple.  `()` is not a prototype.

Comment: @user2579998 The `()` non-parameter notation is kept in C as a backwards compatibility with a very old version of C, called K&R after the original designers Kernighan and Richie. In the original C language parameters didn't need to be specified as instead intimate knowledge on the parameter passing mechanism could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code; it is more nearly an SSCCE than what you provided.  The problem with the null pointer (printed as `(null)`) arises because of the way you were handling the empty list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

typedef struct data
{
    char        *word;
    struct data *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL;

static void  read_content(char *filename);
static node *create_word(char *string);
static void  add_word(node *word);
static void  print_words(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    read_content(argv[1]);
    print_words();

    return 0;
}

void read_content(char *filename)
{
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (input==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    char s[MAX];

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), input) != NULL)
    {
        int length = strlen(s)-1;
        if (s[length] == '\n')
            s[length] = '\0';

        char* token = strtok(s, " ");

        while (token)
        {
            char *s = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(token) + 1));
            strcpy(s, token);
            node *newnode = create_word(s);
            printf("Word: %s\n", newnode->word);
            add_word(newnode);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
}

node *create_word(char *string)
{
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->word = string;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void add_word(node *word)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        head = word;
    else
    {
        node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current=current->next;
        current->next = word;
    }
}

void print_words(void)
{
    for (node *pw = head; pw != NULL; pw = pw->next)
        printf("%s ", pw->word);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The structure of `read_content()` has been modified so it reads all the words in all the lines in the file, rather than just the last line of the file.  The memory allocation of `head` in `main()` was causing the spurious `(null)` in the output.  The code is fixed in `add_word()` too.  The function `print_words()` has been rewritten.  Most of the superfluous material has been ruthlessly eliminated; what's left is more or less necessary to show that the problem is fixed.  There is still room for improvement.  The string allocation and copying in `read_content()` would probably be better handled in `create_word()`; you might or might not want to think about using `strdup()` to duplicate the string.